# Entity Framework, наследование и модификатор new

Tags: c#, entity-framework, наследование

Имеем класс:

```
public class TransferData
{
    public virtual string DeliveryDate { get; set; }
}
```

Дата мне приходит именно строкой, определенного формата и поделать с этим я ничего не могу - контракт менять нельзя.
Имеем унаследованный от него класс для работы с EF:

```
public class Transfer : TransferData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("DeliveryDate")]
    public new DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    public Transfer(TransferData transfer)
    {
        this.DeliveryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                transfer.DeliveryDate,
                                "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }

}
```

Хранить дату я хочу как дату, потому что с ней мне потом работать как с датой, простите за тавтологию.

Дальше получаем (в примере - создаем) экземпляр TransferData, из него создаем экземпляр Transfer и добавляем в базу:

```
        var transferData = new TransferData { DeliveryDate = "2016-11-02" };
        var transfer = new Transfer(transferData);
        context.Transfer.Add(transfer);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Получаем Exception:
`Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`
Смотрим в Details:  "Требуется поле DeliveryDate."
Смотрим в дебаггер:  [image: Exception details]

Мы же работаем с наследником, в наследнике свойство заполнено, зачем EF смотрит в свойство базового класса?
Ну ладно. Понять, простить, надо так надо. Переписываем конструктор, совершая абсолютно бессмысленное действие - заполняем пустой строкой свойство базового класса:

```
public Transfer(TransferData transfer)
{
    ((TransferData)this).DeliveryDate = "";
    this.DeliveryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                            transfer.DeliveryDate,
                            "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

И всё работает.
Это, конечно, радует. Но вопрос: я совсем неправильно понимаю смысл модификатора new и работу EF с унаследованными классами, или это какой-то хитрый баг в EF?

Comment: У меня ошибка не воспроизвелась. А у вас в контексте как DbSet объявлен?

Comment: public virtual DbSet<Transfer> Transfer { get; set; }

Comment: Странно, не воспроизводится ошибка.

Comment: `((TransferData)this).DeliveryDate = "";` - этой строки в конструкторе нет?

Comment: А в БД у вас колонка какого типа получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать, что EF различает свойства только по их именам - ничего при этом не зная про детали реализации. А new - это именно что деталь реализации.

Поэтому, делая модель хранения, желательно:

1. не использовать переопределение свойств (new);
2. не использовать приватную реализацию свойств из интерфейсов.

Ваша проблема не имеет красивого решения. Даже если разберетесь с добавлением - ошибка вылезет где-нибудь еще.

---

Но зачем вы вообще так делаете? Ваше наследование Transfer от TransferData противоречит [LSP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) - вы не можете использовать Transfer вместо TransferData в том коде, который ожидает TransferData.

Уберите ненужное наследование - и все заработает.

Comment: В передаваемый объект могут добавиться свойства (более того, они обязательно добавятся). Не стал тащить в вопрос не относящиеся моменты - там "под капотом" еще ряд связанных объектов, которые надо хранить, плюс другие свойства.